# R Function behaves differently than the code entered line by line

Tags: r, function

I am at a loss. Googling has failed me because I'm not sure I know the right question to ask.

I have a data frame (df1) and my goal is to use a function to get a moving average using forecast::ma.

Here is str(df1)

```
'data.frame':   934334 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ clname  : chr   ...
 $ dos     : Date, format: "2011-10-05" ...
 $ subpCode: chr  
 $ ch1     : chr  "
 $ prov    : chr  
 $ ledger  : chr
```

I have a function that I am trying to write.

```
process <- function(df, y, sub, ...) {


 prog <-   df %>%

    filter(subpCode == sub) %>%

    group_by(dos, subpCode) %>%

    summarise(services = n())

 prog$count_ts <- ts(prog[ , c('services')])


}
```

The problem is that when I run the function, my final result is data object that is 1x1798 and it's just a time series. If I go a run the code line by line I get what I need but my function that hypothetically does the same thing wont work.

Here is my desired result

```
Classes ‘grouped_df’, ‘tbl_df’, ‘tbl’ and 'data.frame': 1718 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ dos     : Date, format: "2010-09-21" "2010-11-18" "2010-11-19" "2010-11-30" ...
 $ subpCode: chr  "CII  " "CII  " "CII  " "CII  " ...
 $ services: int  1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 3 ...
 $ count_ts: Time-Series [1:1718, 1] from 1 to 1718: 1 1 2 2 2 2 1 2 1 3 ...
  ..- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
  .. ..$ : NULL
  .. ..$ : chr "services"
 - attr(*, "vars")= chr "dos"
 - attr(*, "drop")= logi TRU
```

And here is the code that gets it.

```
CII <-   df1 %>%
  filter(subpCode == "CII  ") %>%
  group_by(dos, subpCode) %>%
  summarise(services = n())

CII$count_ts <- ts(CII[ , c('services')])
```

Could someone point me in the right direction. I've exhausted my usual places.

Thanks!

Comment: You want to see the [programming with dplyr vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html). In particular, you need to use `enquo` and `!!` to capture `sub`, because it is looking for values where `subpCode` is literally `sub` rather than whatever `sub` equals. Also, there is no use of the `y` argument that I can see.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look at this and try and get a better understanding. y is defined earlier in the script and it holds the value for the date range.

Comment: What I mean is that it doesn't appear inside the function. Why is it an argument if the function doesn't use it?

Comment: Ah, that would be because in my reworking the function to try and figure out where I was going wrong I dropped it. My unedited function should have read  
process <- function(df, y, sub, ...) {
  

 prog <-   df %>%
    filter(dos > y) %>%
    filter(subpCode == !!sub) %>%
    group_by(dos, subpCode) %>%
    summarise(services = n())

 prog$count_ts <- ts(prog[ , c('services')])
  

}

Answer (score 0):

Following the vignette pointed out by @CalumYou, you should use more something like this:

```
process <- function(df, sub) {
   ## Enquoting sub
   sub <- enquo(sub)

   ## Piping stuff
   prog <-   df %>%
      filter(!! subpCode == sub) %>%
      group_by(dos, subpCode) %>%
      summarise(services = n())

   prog$count_ts <- ts(prog[ , c('services')])

   ## Returning the prog object
   return(prog)
}
```